# Move Node.js TCP server from localhost to VPS (Openshift)

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, port, openshift

I have a working node.js server when it runs on localhost, i can send and receive data from my client (written in java). However, when i move the server.js to the VPS application at Openshift (free) the client can no longer connect to the server.js.

I've uploaded the files as instructed, I open a SSH connection via terminal to server, navigate to the repo folder (where uploaded files is), run "node server.js" (it appears to be online, no error and the on.('online',..) events activates.

And when i then run the client on my computer it isn't able to connect to the server.js.

server.js:

```
var os      = require('os');
var HOST    = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP;;
var PORT    = process.env.PORT || 80;
var cluster = require('cluster');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
var net     = require('net');

console.log("Hostname: " + HOST + "\nPort: " + PORT);

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    cluster.SCHED_RR;


    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    Object.keys(cluster.workers).forEach(function(id){
        console.log("I am runnong with ID: " + cluster.workers[id].process.pid);
    });

    console.log('\n');

    cluster.on('online', function(worker) {
        console.log('Worker: ' + worker.process.pid + " listning on port " + PORT);
    });

    cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal){
        console.log("Worker " + worker.process.pid + " died")
    });

} else {

    // Load the TCP Library
    net = require('net');

    // Keep track of the chat clients
    var clients = [];

    // Start a TCP Server
    var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {

        console.log('\n'); 
        // Identify this client
        socket.name = socket.remoteAddress + ":" + socket.remotePort 

        // Put this new client in the list
        clients.push(socket);

        // Send a nice welcome message and announce
        socket.write("Welcome " + socket.name + "\n\n");
        broadcast(socket.name + " joined the chat\n", socket);

        // Handle incoming messages from clients.
        socket.on('data', function (data) {
            //var ls = net.connect(5001, 'localhost');

            var string = data + "";

            //console.log(string);
            var message = string.split("|");

            broadcast("    Passing data from "+message[2]+" to "+message[1] + "\n    " + message[3], socket);


            //ls.write(string);
            //ls.end();

        });

        socket.on('connect', function(){
          broadcast("\n    New connection opened.\n");
        });

        // Remove the client from the list when it leaves
        socket.on('end', function () {
            clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
            broadcast("\n" + socket.name + " left the chat.\n");
        });

        // Send a message to all clients
        function broadcast(message, sender) {
            clients.forEach(function (client) {
                // Don't want to send it to sender
                if (client === sender) return;
                client.write(message);
            });
            // Log it to the server output too
            process.stdout.write(message)
        }

    })

    server.listen(PORT, HOST);

    server.on('error', function (e) {
        if (e.code == 'EADDRINUSE') {
            console.log('Address in use, retrying...');
            setTimeout(function () {
                server.close();
                server.listen(PORT, HOST);
            }, 1000);
        }
        else if (e.code == 'ECONNREFUSED') {
            console.log('Connection refused');
        }
    });

}
```

Client.java (relevant parts)

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s = getPackage();

    try {
        System.out.print("\n");

        /*InetAddress addr;
        Socket sock = new Socket("ex-std-node272.prod.rhcloud.com", 80);
        addr = sock.getInetAddress();
        System.out.println("Connected to " + addr);*/


        Socket skt = new Socket("127.10.100.1", 80);
        BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(new
        InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));

        DataOutputStream outStream = new DataOutputStream(skt.getOutputStream());

        //System.out.print("   Received string: '");

        //while (!inStream.ready()) {}
        //System.out.print(inStream.readLine()); // Read one line and output it

        System.out.print("'\n\n");

        // Send first message
        //outStream.writeByte(1);
        outStream.writeUTF(s);
        //outStream.flush(); // Send off the data
        //outStream.write(b,0,b.length);
        outStream.flush(); // Send off the data


    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.print("    Error: " + e);
    }

}
```

When i run the server.js (at the VPS) it gives me the Hostname: 127.10.100.1 and Port: 80 which i've then pasted into the client.

So, what do i need to do with the code i have to make it connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to listen on port 8080, not port 80.  Try reading over this section of the Developer Center on Port Binding: https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-port-binding-routing.html

Comment: If (and only if) i remove HOST from the listen call and change PORT to 8080 in server.js it starts to listen to 8080. But i still can't connect from the client (changing the port to 8080 /8000 (keeping the ip). Any more ideas?

Comment: What cartridge type did you use?  You should not have to ssh to the server to run your application.  Try using this as a template: https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-nodejs-http-and-websocket-example for what you should do.

Comment: I've been able to use the client and server from example but my java client just doesn't want to if you have any idea on how to solve that feel free to tell moi, but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to note is that PORT in your server.js should be made equal to `process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT` or `8080` as Corey already mentioned.

The second problem is that when you run your client on your local machine, the host you should be connecting to the URL given to your application when you created it something like `http://<appname>-<domain>.rhcloud.com`. You can see your application url when you issue the command:

```
rhc show-app <appname>
```